# Looking for a user suggestion script

Tags: looking-for-a-script, suggestions

I'm looking for a script that would easily fit or be customized to work as a suggestion script where users can submit suggestions anonymously and have them be displayed on one page and either upvoted or downvoted like digg or reddit without user accounts.

Basically i want users to be able to submit an idea and the other users like or dislike it and no one is track for voting, commenting or submitting.

Comment: Your request is a bit vague :) And what have u tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can build this with WordPress. First create a form that generates posts as drafts in a specific category. You moderate the "Suggestion" approve/post it and they can all display on one page. You can then use any popular "like" post plugin. I would use one which stores likes as custom post meta data so that you can query it as needed and sort/filter based on most popular "Suggestions" You can customize the page which displays all the "Suggestions" so that it shows the title, date, no name, comments either yes or no etc. You'll have full control of this.